# getting reactive native async error in useffect

Tags: reactjs, async-await

```
Argument of type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EffectCallback'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'
```

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const users = await axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/?page=1&results=10&nat=us");
    setUsers(users.data.results);
  }, []);
```

I am getting this error while using async in react native

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // declare the data fetching function
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const data = await fetch('https://yourapi.com');
  }

  // call the function
  fetchData()
    // make sure to catch any error
    .catch(console.error);
}, [])
```